# How to get this recommendation letter template to work

Tags: errors

I'm trying to get the recommendation letter template from the following site to work, but I'm too stupid to get it to compile correctly.

tedsider.org

I downloaded all the latex related files:

BibTeX database (.bib)
Class file (.cls) for letters 
with scanned signature
.cls for recommendations
Example .tex file 
for a recommendation
BibTeX style file (.bst) for Analysis journal
.bst for Phil Review

put them in one folder and then compiled the RECOMMENDATION.TEX file using Texmaker. I keep getting loads of errors. I think it'd be good to have the solution here since this latex template is one of the first results on google and probably one of the first things many people will try. 
I got the following complete error report during compilation:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=latex 2014.10.31) 20 JAN 2015 05:15
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**RECOMMENDATION.tex
(./RECOMMENDATION.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 10 languages loaded.
(./university_recommendation.cls
Document Class: university_recommendation
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(./university_letter.cls
Document Class: university_letter
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls
Document Class: letter 1999/04/29 v1.2z Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\longindentation=\dimen102
\indentedwidth=\dimen103
\labelcount=\count79
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty
Package: times 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 91.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2006/04/12 ver 3.3 Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\tsheader=\box26
\universitylogo=\box27
)
Runaway argument?
{\parbox {\textwidth }{ } \par \sbox {\tsheader }{\parbox [b]{\textwidth \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \sbox.
<inserted text>
\par
l.30
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
) (./RECOMMENDATION.aux)
\openout1 = `RECOMMENDATION.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 7.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
! Font OT1/ptm/m/n/12=ptmr7t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again>
relax
l.7 \begin{document}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
Missing character: There is no J in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 5 in font nullfont!
! Font OT1/ptm/m/n/14.4=ptmr7t at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
<to be read again>
relax
l.13 \opening{}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 13.
! Font OT1/ptm/bx/n/14.4=ptmb7t at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not f
ound.
<to be read again>
relax
l.13 \opening{}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
! Font \OT1/ptm/b/n/14.4=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.13 \opening{}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
Missing character: There is no R in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/sc' in size <14.4> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/sc' tried instead on input line 13.
! Font OT1/ptm/bx/sc/14.4=ptmbc7t at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
found.
<to be read again>
relax
l.13 \opening{}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
! Font \OT1/ptm/b/sc/14.4=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.13 \opening{}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
Missing character: There is no R in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no O in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no M in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no M in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no N in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no D in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <12> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <8> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <6> on input line 13.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 13--14
[]
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no X in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no O in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no F in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no L in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no R in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no G in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no O in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no S in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no H in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no R in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.17 \closing{}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
Missing character: There is no M in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no Y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no N in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no A in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no M in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no P in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no P in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OT1+pcr on input line 17.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1pcr.fd
File: ot1pcr.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
)
! Font OT1/pcr/m/n/12=pcrr7t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again>
relax
l.17 \closing{}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character M).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character Y).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character E).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character M).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character A).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character I).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character L).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character A).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character D).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character D).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character R).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character E).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character S).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character S).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $
l.17 \closing{}
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
! Font OT1/ptm/m/n/10=ptmr7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again>
relax
l.18 \end{letter}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
[1
] (./RECOMMENDATION.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
692 strings out of 494769
8792 string characters out of 6175771
55505 words of memory out of 5000000
4064 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
6376 words of font info for 23 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
80 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
38i,6n,23p,213b,225s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
Output written on RECOMMENDATION.dvi (1 page, 188 bytes).
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code but the file appears to have a missing `}` around line 30 the `\sbox` argument is not closed, and your local distribution appears not to have the font metrics for times installed correctly which seems strange as they are a standard part of texlive. That said you are using the `times` package which is very old and not really recommended these days/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unclear or do you want to write an answer anyway?

Comment: @Johannes_B unclear